# Webcrawling: Selenium do not give me the latest version of the website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new to crawling and the language python, but my University wants me to do my bachelor project in this kinda topic so.
The Problem i am facing is, that during my crawling through the website there are buttons that expand and collapse a container. There are two of the "Alle anzeigen" and "Sterne anzeigen". i need to click on them to trigger the javascript event that loads the container. The container exist before the Event but does not contains the content i need yet.
I can click the buttons, that is not the problem. The problem is that sometimes the container with the things i want are not in the version that Selenium give me after the crawling process.
I use a chrome driver and a chrome.exe. both of them are integrated into the project and both of them are on version 119.0.6045.105, i tried a new version but with the same result

```
 def connectAndGet(url):
        url = url
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptionsSettingMaster())
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.get(url)

        # Handle cookie consent
        try:
            consent_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "consent-accept-button")))
            if consent_button:
                consent_button.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Cookie consent button not found or not clickable" + str(e))

        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        while True:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'index__contentBlock__KbUvv')))


                # for the button "Mehr anzeigen"
                buttonMA = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "reviews-show-all-button")
                if buttonMA:
                    for but in buttonMA:
                        actions.move_to_element(but).perform()
                        but.click()
                        time.sleep(randomizSleepOneToThree())

                # for the button "Sterne anzeigen"
                buttonSA = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "reviews-show-star-ratings-button")
                if buttonSA:
                    for buts in buttonSA:
                        if buts.text == "Sterne anzeigen":
                            actions.move_to_element(buts).perform()
                            buts.click()
                            time.sleep(randomizSleepOneToThree())

                # Wait for the button to be clickable "mehr Bewertungen lesen" (adjust selector accordingly)
                button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,   "reviews-read-more-cta")))
                if button:
                    button.click()
                    time.sleep(randomizSleepOneToThree())

            except TimeoutException:
                print("Timeout waiting for element.")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

        time.sleep(20)
        html_text = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
        soup.prettify()
        driver.quit()
        return soup

def randomizSleepOneToThree():
    min_sleep_time = 1  # Minimum sleep time in seconds
    max_sleep_time = 3  # Maximum sleep time in seconds
    return random.uniform(min_sleep_time, max_sleep_time)

def chromeOptionsSettingMaster():
    # Set the working directory to the location of your chromedriver and chrome
    # Get the directory of the current script
    script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # add the path to chromedriver.exe
    final_directory = os.path.join(script_directory, "chromedriver", "chromedriver.exe")
    # add the path to chrome.exe
    final_binary = os.path.join(script_directory, "chromeBrowser", "chrome.exe")
    # manipulate the chrome binary to our test chrome
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = final_binary
    chrome_options.add_argument("executable_path={}".format(final_directory))
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # important for windows
    chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

    return chrome_options
```

[image: First Image]

this one should look like

[image: Second Image]

the difference is the div element next to the h4 element, the div contains a span and the span has the attr data-score and i need the data-score

You can use https://www.kununu.com/de/procar-automobile/kommentare as link to try.

Comment: Without additional details it is just guessing, so please provide some more information in example a url that do not come up with expected results. Have you tried to observe the behaviour in non headleass mode? In addition -  On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: not clearing the cache but i disabled it now with chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-cache") and nothing has changed